# Indesign bleeding makings 4x6 into 4.50 x 6.50 instead of 4.25 x 6.25?

Tags: adobe-indesign

New to indesign and when I have a document thats 4x6 and when I add the bleeding to be .25 the red border(which I assume is the bleeding border) is actually enlarged to 4.50 by 6.50. Is there any reason why?Thanks!

Comment: If the spec you are given says something like "trim 4 inches; bleed 4.25", they are saying **total bleed** of .25, which would be .125 on each end of the appropriate axis. With respect to indesign's dialogs, there is a chain icon next to the bleed fields, "break the chain" and the fields can be filled in independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

.25" on **all sides** -- left .25" + right .25" = .5"

What you are seeing is standard.